# bumpversion and build at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, setuptools

I simply want to run `bumpversion minor` and have it make a commit and tag, but also want to have it build based on that new version.

When I run `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` it creates a file based on the version in the setup.py file. So the problem is that if I run this before `bumpversion` it creates a filename based on the old version number rather than what I'll bump it too. If I run `bumpversion` before the build, now it is committed and tagged the version bump and does not yet have the updated dist/ packages.

Is there a way to build as part of the bumpversion so that it is included in the automatic commit and tag? Or do I just need to turn off the automatic commit/tag and instead run `bumpversion`, then build it, then manually commit and tag it?

Comment: *Is there a way to build as part of the `bumpversion`?* Certainly no. *If I run `bumpversion` before the build, now it is committed and tagged the version bump and does not yet have the updated dist/ packages.* In what way it's a problem? You do `bump`, commit, tag, build, upload and push. That's all.

Comment: @phd Would you not want the updated build/packages to be a part of the commit/tag version bump though? The packages are version controlled as this is an internal project and anyone using it will grab the latest package from the dist/ folder in the repo.

Comment: I don't care about atomicity. I bump, commit, tag, build, upload and push in a shell script, that's what I call "during bump". After that I send messages (email, IM) to announce the change. I don't care about 3 seconds pauses between tag, upload and push.

Comment: @phd my concern is more than the tagged commit does not have the release package within it so if you checked it out it would not be there.

Comment: I push commits and tags after uploading.